# connect to facebook chat server, no response

Tags: facebook, api, xmpp, chat

I am writing php code to let my app connect to facebook chat server as an XMPP client.

I have managed the Authentication part, and received "success" msg from facebook.

I have managed several more message exchange between my app and facebook server. I reached the point that I have received a response contains the clients JID for the session.

However, after I send

```
<iq id="_xmpp_session1" type="set"><session xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session"/></iq>
```

I got no response from facebook chat server.

Anyone knows what went wrong? Is my request xml msg correct?

Thanks!

Comment: What XML message? Please put it in your question. "" != XML

Answer (score 0):

From section 3 of [RFC 3921](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3921.txt), the correct example is:

```
<iq to='example.com'
    type='set'
    id='sess_1'>
  <session xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-session'/>
</iq>
```

Make sure you've got a `to` attribute.

Comment: I added to attribute, but it still did not work. it is very strange that the app just hangs there, does not send the msg out. If I skip this msg, continue with the presence msg, at least php tries to send out the presence msg, but no response msg from the server. My third experiment is to make an obvious error in the msg, in that case, at least I receive a server error msg.